# Arrows navigation based on which section are you in

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Does anyone know if there exists a plugin or similar to achieve navigation like on this website: http://discover.store.sony.com/tablet/#entertainment

I am talking about up and down arrows that appear when hovering over top pr bottom part of the screen.

Comment: Look at the address bar while scrolling. Every part of site will be change `#` after url.

Comment: The plugin is in the page you linked here:
<script src="assets/js/sonytab.js"></script> See the HTML on this page to get how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, this shouldn't be too difficult to write yourself. Here's a starting point to achieve the arrows when hovering over certain parts of the page. You would just need to handle  attaching specific links to the arrows depending on which section the user is currently looking at.

See the comments for more details.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8yhs7/2/)**

Note that in the Fiddle I have used `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` to get the current mouse position, but in reality you should use `event.screenX` and `event.screenY`. Because the demo in the fiddle is embedded as a small window into the actual page, using the latter would not work.

```
// Define how wide the areas should be
// where the arrow appears
var top_nav_height = 70;
var bottom_nav_height = 70;

// Get some dimensions
var page_height = $(document).height();
var half_arrow_size = $('.uparrow').width() / 2;

// Listen to the user moving their mouse
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    // Where is the mouse?
    var pos_y = event.screenY;    // Distance from top of the page
    var pos_x = event.screenX;    // Distance from left of the page
    var in_area;
    // Leave a 5px space to hide the arrows when 
    // the pointer moves outside of the page
    if (pos_y <= top_nav_height
        && pos_y > 5) {
        in_area = 'top_nav';
    }
    else if (page_height - pos_y <= bottom_nav_height
             && page_height - pos_y > 5) {
        in_area = 'bottom_nav';
    }

    // Show the arrow when in a nav area
    switch(in_area) {

        // We are in the top nav area
        case 'top_nav': 
            // Show the .uparrow and have it follow the mouse
            $('.uparrow')
                .show()
                .css({
                    top: pos_y - half_arrow_size, 
                    left: pos_x - half_arrow_size
                });
            break;

        // We are in the bottom nav area
        case 'bottom_nav':
            // Show the .bottomarrow and have it follow the mouse
            $('.bottomarrow')
                .show()
                .css({
                    top: pos_y - half_arrow_size, 
                    left: pos_x - half_arrow_size
                });
            break;

        // We aren't in a nav area
        default:
            // Hide both arrows
            $('.uparrow, .bottomarrow').hide();
    }

    // Decide where the arrow should link

});
```

To handle the links, I guess you could also have a separate set of arrows on each section of your page, so the targets they link to can pretty much be hardcoded.

Comment: Thanks Elise! This a very good starting point. If you could just explain how to use hardcoded links, or how to get the current section and then use that href for the link. The thing is that I am having trouble getting current section href, because it clashes with skrollr.js, which is a plugin I use for this website. If you are interested, here is the link: http://m10.auroralighting.com/m10V2/index.html

Comment: Update: Funny, you said that I should change event.page to event.screen, but it only works with page, if I use screen, the behaviour is not as intended.

Comment: Update-2: Unfortunately, it won't work. At least it won't work as is, you can check the above link, the arrow only displays in the top part of the website, and that is it. I guess this is down to using page(X,Y), but if screen is used I get no arrows at all.

Comment: Hmm, I might have mixed something up there with getting the mouse position, then, I was never too sure when to use which of those. The problem is probably that the bottom arrow is displayed only on the very bottom 100px of the page when you're scrolled all the way down. Sorry I can't be of more help!

Comment: Regarding the linking, this is tricky, too. I've been cracking my head for a while, and I think the most solid solution I've come up with so far is to simply calculate how far down the user has scrolled (see jquery's `scrollTop()`), and assign a section to it based on that. This is easiest when all sections are a 100% height of the window, which I understand is the case the website you linked.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with scrollTop, but I am afraid that the arrows will be hard to implement for someone with my knowledge of JS. Think I will need help from a professional:((  Once again, thanks.